# VueJS - Post array of object using jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, vue.js

This is My Code:

```
<div class="container" id="app">
   <div id='res' class='alert alert-info'></div>
   <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
     <tr class="w-100">
       <td>  Title </td> 
       <td>  URL </td>
     </tr>
     <tr v-for="res in results" >
       <td>  <input :id=res.id :value=res.LinkTitle class="w-100">  </td>
       <td> <input :id=res.id :value=res.URL class="w-100" dir='ltr'> </td> 
     </tr>
   </table>
   <div class='w-100 text-left'>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveData">Save</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Results is array of objects returned from database.

```
<script>
     const vm = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       created: function()
       {
          this.loadData();
       },
       data: {
         results: []

       },
       methods:{

           loadData: function()
           {
                $.ajax({url: "/api/links", context:this , success: function(jres){
                     this.results = JSON.parse(jres);
               }});

           }
           ,
           saveData: function()
           {

                   $.ajax({
                   url: "/api/links", 
                   method:"post" , 
                   data: JSON.stringify(this.results) , 
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   dataType: 'json' ,
                   context:this ,
                   success:
                    function(res){
                      $("#res").html(res);
                      //alert(res);
                    }});

           }
       }

     });
   </script>
```

LoadData works fine. SaveData is triggered but not showing any results. It's supposed  just to show me a "test string".

EDIT :
I removed dataType: 'json'  and it shows me test string. But PHP $_POST array is empty.

Comment: `this` inside success function refers to function not data object. Try to change the function to arrow function.

Comment: It's not the problem. Thank you,  I tried reading raw input from php://input and it returns the posted data but $_POST array is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kalimah said, `this` here refers to the `ajax` function and not the `Vue` instance. It's the same when using Axios. Try putting `this` in a `var` outside of the ajax function so that it can refer to the parent object:

```
saveData: function() {
    const self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/links", 
        method:"post", 
        data: JSON.stringify(self.results), // Replace 'this' with self'' 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this,
        success: function(res) {
            $("#res").html(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's a small example to illustrate the issue. In this case, the parent object is the `window` object, but in your case, it will be the `Vue` instance:

```js
(function() {
    const self = this;
    const thisEl = document.querySelector('.this')
    const selfEl = document.querySelector('.self')
    $.ajax({
        url: "/", 
        beforeSend: function(res) {
            thisEl.innerText = this
            selfEl.innerText = self
        },
    });
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="this"></h3>
<h3 class="self"></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you, But as I said before it works. There is no problem in calling this. Context properties is there to solve it. I tried reading raw input from php://input and it returns the posted data but $_POST array is still empty.

Comment: Ah I see @Vahid2015 , that makes sense. Can it not maybe be the URL. What if you adding the file extension in the URL e.g. `/api/links.php`